# Dealing with different versions of Hibernate libs

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven, password-encryption, jasypt

I have an existing application using a DB called EXAMPLE, which uses a kind-of-old version of hibernate.

Users' passwords are stored as **org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType**

```
<typedef name="encryptedString" class="org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType">
    <param name="encryptorRegisteredName">jasyptHibernateEncryptor</param>
</typedef>

    <property name="password" type="encryptedString">
        <column name="pwd" length="254" not-null="true" />
    </property>
```

I don't know if it's always like this but basically, when querying for a user, it automatically decrypts their password so it is in clear text.

Now, on the very same database, there is a new web application running (call it webapp2). This one encrypts passwords differently and in an undecryptable way.

What I was asked to do is migrate the old users to "the new way", and what I did was to create a maven project with 3 modules:

- **module1** (aka oldie) should just be able to query the database in the
  old way (so that for every query on the user table I can have the
  user's password in clear text)
- **module2** (aka newie) should just query the database in the new way.
- **module3** should have one dummy class (for now it's a junit thingy)
  that uses UserService from module1 and UserService from module2
  respectively for read users password (clear text) and set it back the
  new way.

THE ISSUE:
What I'm facing is a whole lot of issues with module3 **having to deal with different versions of hibernate libs** and what not.

On my configuration of **module3** (they're all spring applications) I'm autowiring services and daos from both module1 and module2 making a lot of mess which ends up in trouble.

What appears to be happening is that there's a mix of dependencies that makes instantiations of sessionFactories or daos (for now) impossible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use both versions of Hibernate at the same time. You could

- extract both encryption/decryption parts in a small utility class, and just use JDBC to decrypt using the old way and encrypt using the new way.
- or just run a first pass with the first module to extract all the passwords in clear text and put them in a file or in a dedicated database table, then run a second pass with the second module to extract the clear text passwords and store them in the entities to encrypt them using the new method.

Comment: second the opinion, provided you have liberty to do that.